# Python: List out of range

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to build a basic encoder and decoder to learn some Python. That's the current code I have:

```
import time

def mainSub():
    sString = input('Please enter a string:')
    sChoose = input('Would you like to [e]ncrypt or [d]ecrypt?:')
    encrypts = ["a","362","b","637","c","391","d","678","e","912","f","718","g","461","h","888","i","123","j","817","k","571","l","111","m","036","n","182","o","951","p","711","q","500","r","125","s","816","t","183","u","619","v","678","w","911","x","719","y","567","z","678"," ","-"]
    if sChoose == "e":
        for x in range(0, len(encrypts)):
            sOutput = sString
            sOutput = sOutput.replace(encrypts[x], encrypts[x+1])
    elif sChoose == "d":
        for x in range(0, len(encrypts)):
            sOutput = sString
            sOutput = sOutput.replace(encrypts[x+1], encrypts[x])
    else:
        print("You did not choose for encrypt or decrypt. Please only enter e or d.")
        print(sOutput)

while True:
    mainSub()
```

However, the console aborts whenever it should replace with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Max/Desktop/test.py", line 20, in <module>
  mainSub()   File "C:/Users/Max/Desktop/test.py", line 10, in mainSub
  sOutput = sOutput.replace(encrypts[x], encrypts[x+1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can't find the error. Can someone help me?

Comment: This `encrypts[x+1]` will give you the error when the list has reached its end then you try to access an item that "should be" after the end a.k.a one-off error.

Comment: if `x==len(encrypts) - 1` (at the end of the range), then `encrypts[x+1]` does not exist. Also, you can omit the `start` parameter of range: `range(len(encrypts))`

Comment: Really, you should probably use a pair of dicts for this...

Comment: @Kevin or one dict and loop over `.iteritems`, swapping which replaces the other based on the encrypt/ decrypt request.

Comment: btw, not related to the IndexError, but the more I read this, the more baffled I get.  You're doing a string.replace, then throwing away the result and doing another string replace?  Did you mean to have `sOutput = sString` outside of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

As per the other replies, you're getting the good old off-by-one index thing.  One potential solution is to not do any index fiddling at all:

```
# Let's put this line out of the for loop to prevent clearing changes every iteration
sOutput = sString 
for current_item, next_item in zip(encrypts, encrypts[1:]):
    sOutput = sOutput.replace(current_item, next_item)
```

`zip` takes two iterables, and returns tuples containing one item of each iterable, ending when the shortest iterable is exhausted.  By zipping `encrypts` with `encrypts[1:]`, you get a series of tuples containing adjacent elements in `encrypts`.

If `encrypts` is quite large, it would be more memory efficient to use `izip` from the `itertools` module.  Use `izip` exactly as you use `zip`, and it will return a lazily-evaluated generator object, rather than creating the entire list of tuples first.

**Edit:** OK upon inspecting your code again there are several things quite fundamentally wrong with it.  What I have above replicates what your code does without producing the index error, but what your code does is actually incorrect.  You actually need to pair the first item with the second, the third with the fourth etc, while you're currently pairing the first with the second, the second with the third, the third with the fourth etc.

Here's how you can do the encryption:

```
for odd_elem, even_elem in zip(encrypts[::2], encrypts[1::2]):
    sOutput = sOutput.replace(odd_elem, even_elem)
```

Or as @padraic-cunningham says, use a dict since you're encrypting one character at a time.  Here's how you might do the encrypt:

```
encrypt_dict = dict(zip(encrypts[0::2], encrypts[1::2]))
sOutput = ''.join(encrypt_dict[char] for char in sString)
```

Decrypts is harder using dicts, because you're not encrypting everything into 3 numbers (spaces get converted to '-').  It's still doable by splitting on '-' first then further chunking into 3 numbers each, then running it through a decryption dict.  Or you can just convert spaces into '---' as per @padraic-cunningham.

Answer (score 0):

Over here suppose the length of your encrypts array is 8.

```
for x in range(0, len(encrypts)):
            sOutput = sString
            sOutput = sOutput.replace(encrypts[x], encrypts[x+1])
elif sChoose == "d":
    for x in range(0, len(encrypts)):
        sOutput = sString
        sOutput = sOutput.replace(encrypts[x+1], encrypts[x])
```

So for a zero indexed array x will iterate over a range of 0-7 when x is 7 :-
sOutput = sOutput.replace(encrypts[7], encrypts[8+1])
in the above line you are trying to access a location encrypts[9] which is out of range.

so your program should go in range 0 to len(encrypts)-1

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop

```
for x in range(0, len(encrypts)):
```

which means that `x` will take values from `0` to `len(encrypts) - 1`.

For example, if `len(encrypts)` is `4`, `x` will take values from `0` to `3`.

Now, you are trying to access to `encrypts[x+1]`. In the last iteration (where `x` will be `len(encrypts) - 1`), the expression

```
encrypts[x+1]
```

will be equivalent to

```
encrypts[len(encrypts) - 1 + 1]
encrypts[len(encrypts)]
```

This will produce an `Error` because lists index start in `0`, not in `1`.

**So, what can you do?**

You can decrease the loop range in 1:

```
for x in range(0, len(encrypts)-1):
```

But take care of the effets that this change implies.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to encrypt and decrypt using  dicts:

```
def main_sub():
    while True:
        s_string = input('Please enter a string:')
        s_choose = input('Would you like to [e]ncrypt or [d]ecrypt?:')
        decrypts = {'571': 'k', '888': 'h', '391': 'c', '111': 'l', '036': 'm', '951': 'o', '637': 'b', '---': ' ', '182': 'n', '183': 't', '362': 'a', '816': 's', '817': 'j', '619': 'u', '678': 'z', '719': 'x', '718': 'f', '461': 'g', '711': 'p', '567': 'y', '123': 'i', '125': 'r', '911': 'w', '500': 'q', '912': 'e'}
        encrypts = {' ': '---', 'a': '362', 'c': '391', 'b': '637', 'e': '912', 'd': '678', 'g': '461', 'f': '718', 'i': '123', 'h': '888', 'k': '571', 'j': '817', 'm': '036', 'l': '111', 'o': '951', 'n': '182', 'q': '500', 'p': '711', 's': '816', 'r': '125', 'u': '619', 't': '183', 'w': '911', 'v': '678', 'y': '567', 'x': '719', 'z': '678'}
        if s_choose == "e":
            s_output = "".join([encrypts[k] for k in s_string])
            return s_output
        elif s_choose == "d":
            s_output = "".join([decrypts[s_string[k:k+3]] for k in range(0,len(s_string),3)])
            return s_output
        else:
            print("You did not choose for encrypt or decrypt. Please only enter e or d.")
In [2]: main_sub()
Please enter a string:foo
Would you like to [e]ncrypt or [d]ecrypt?:e
Out[2]: '718951951'

In [3]: main_sub()
Please enter a string:718951951
Would you like to [e]ncrypt or [d]ecrypt?:d
Out[3]: 'foo'


In [4]: main_sub()
Please enter a string:foo bar
Would you like to [e]ncrypt or [d]ecrypt?:e
Out[4]: '718951951---637362125'

In [5]: main_sub()
Please enter a string:718951951---637362125
Would you like to [e]ncrypt or [d]ecrypt?:d
Out[5]: 'foo bar'
```